# Node eslint adding prefix `src` despite tsconfig settings

Tags: typescript, import, eslint, eslintrc

I'm running `npx eslint --fix src` from my `client` folder. If a relative import is specified in my codebase, I want my git hook to basically run the `npx eslint` command to convert it to an absolute path. However, the path that it's getting converted to has `src/` prefixed with it (despite me specifying `baseUrl` in the compilerOptions).

Example:

```
import { UserContext } from '../../services/userContext'; 

goes to 

import { UserContext } from 'src/services/userContext';

I want:

import { UserContext } from 'services/userContext';
```

My folder structure looks like so (given i'm using Node and wanted a mono repo for server and client):

```
repo/
  .eslintrc
  client/
    tsconfig.json
    src/
    <all my client code and components>
  server/
```

My **.eslintrc**:

```
// .eslintrc
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "commonjs": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "no-relative-import-paths"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "project": [
      "server/tsconfig.json",
      "client/tsconfig.json"
    ]
      },
      "node": {
        "moduleDirectory": [
          "client/src/",
          "client/node_modules",
          "server/src",
          "server/node_modules"
      ],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/order": [
      "warn",
      {
        "alphabetize": {
          "caseInsensitive": true,
          "order": "asc"
        },
        "groups": [["builtin", "external"]],
        "newlines-between": "always"
      }
    ],
    "import/no-unresolved": [1, {"commonjs": false, "amd": false}],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "no-relative-import-paths/no-relative-import-paths": [
      "warn",
      { "allowSameFolder": true }
    ]
  },
  "
```

My **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Is there any config that looks wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ah interesting. I was running:

```
~/repo/client/
$ npx eslint --fix src
```

which then prefixed the autocorrected absolute import paths with /src/. However, if I run:

```
~/repo/client/src
$ npx eslint --fix .
```

That does not occur and the paths look good. I'd love to know a way to make that idempotent and not have to worry about where we're running eslint from.

---

**UPDATE**

This doesn't actually work. Why wouldn't I be able to run `eslint --fix .` from the root directory?